# get SQL to work with a select form element, comma delimited

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, delimited

I'm trying to allow users to view only certain records, where query variables are given by the user using a form. The form contains a datepicker and 3 select-elements where users can select multiple options, the allowed options are populated by SQL using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

The date selection works, but the SELECT-list only works when one value is selected. I feel that the problem is being caused by incorrect SQL on the 'results' page. I don't know how to make SQL work with a comma delimited string (example: user1, user2, user3 etc. This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM exp_core
WHERE `time` >= startdate 
AND `time` <= enddate 
AND user LIKE uservar 
AND type LIKE typevar 
AND trnsact LIKE trnsactvar
```

`uservar`, `typevar` and `trnsactvar` are comma delimited form variables. Who knows how to make SQL treat these values as separate values?

Comment: this can be done in mysql, but is is easier to do in php. are you using php? If not, check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691942/mysql-iterate-through-elements-of-a-split-string-and-do-things-with-them?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

For multiple variables, you have to use the IN operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM exp_core
WHERE `time` >= startdate 
AND `time` <= enddate 
AND user IN (uservar) 
AND type IN (typevar) 
AND trnsact IN (trnsactvar)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. It still displays everything (or nothing).

Comment: In case the values passed are not integers, you have to enclose each value in quotes.